# In Powershell, what is the difference between -Property and -ExpandProperty?

Tags: command-line, powershell, powershell-ise

Running the cmdlets, the outputs are slightly different, and I'm just trying to understand the difference between the two cmdlets and why you would use one over the other.

Example:

```
Get-Date | Select -Property DayOfWeek
```

Output:

```
DayOfWeek
---------
Saturday
```

```
Get-Date | Select -ExpandProperty DayOfWeek

Saturday
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have tried several searches wording them several different ways trying to get any information on those commands, and I couldn't find anything. You just gave me a whole source of information for future questions I may have as well, so again, thank you! I am grateful :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Intro

You can inspect any object in Powershell by feeding it to **Format-List** cmdlet:

```
PS> Get-Date | Format-List

DisplayHint : DateTime
Date        : 2018-10-21 0:00:00
Day         : 21
DayOfWeek   : Sunday
DayOfYear   : 294
Hour        : 18
Kind        : Local
Millisecond : 28
Minute      : 38
Month       : 10
Second      : 36
Ticks       : 636757439160281486
TimeOfDay   : 18:38:36.0281486
Year        : 2018
DateTime    : 21 жовтня 2018 р. 18:38:36
```

Then, you can change the object, eg. create the new object with subset of properties of original object. You do this using **Select-Object** cmdlet and with the list of required properties in `-Property` parameter.

> `Select-Object` has default alias `Select`, but I suggest that while learning Powershell and exchanging your code with external parties, eg. Superuser.com you do not use aliases, but only full names of cmdlets for the sake of clarity

#### Answer

- `Get-Date | Select-Object -Property DayOfWeek` will create object which has only one property `DayOfWeek` of the object returned by **Get-Date**
- `Get-Date | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DayOfWeek` will return the String with the *content* of `DayOfWeek` property

Comment: Those two parameters of `select` are explained more here too https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-6

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT thanks, this will be helpful as well. Looking at this question I have remembered that these "obvious" things like difference between situations when command returns string with something vs. returning simlarly-looking object are not clearly described in tutorials and I had to come through very non-intuitive learning curve until everything come to its places.

Comment: Understood, sometimes the wording of explanations and such can be hard to interpret. Getting in there and running, comparing, and reading seems to work well for me but a more clear and concise explanation never hurts.